# Cursor does not return any value

Tags: android

I'm choosing an image from gallery and uploading that image to server and also set image to `ImageView`. I'm refering [this](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/626144/android-image-uploading-to-server-from-gallery) site. My `data.getData()` returns following string:

```
content://media/external/images/media/22
```

But my app get crashed at following line:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1){

        Uri uri= data.getData();
        Log.e("uri", String.valueOf(uri));
        mImagePath = getPath(this,uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath);
        mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

public String getPath(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    finally {
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does logcat say?

Comment: My logcat doesnt give any error.

Comment: without the error log it is hard to say but a wild guess is to check your permissions first in your manifest if you can access this resource

Comment: can you tell me which permission should i have to add?

Comment: based on the uri, I suggest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: add these permissions in your manifest file   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Thanx it works. update your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the URI you have provided I suggest to add the following permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have added the permission all thing working fine but however in mine getPath method the cursor is not getting any value.Can you pleae let me know where am i doing wrong

Comment: @Mrunal dump your Cursor then and see what's inside: DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()

Comment: My cursor contains value like ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@3860